# Discord.js: create a unique invite link that only works for a specific user?

Tags: oauth-2.0, discord, discord.js

Is it possible using Discord.js + Discord's oAuth2 flow to do the following:

1. Display a button which says something like "Request Invite Link", which when clicked triggers the oAuth2 flow, requesting the user sign in via their Discord account.
2. Take the returned Discord user ID of the user, and generate a unique invite link for a server, which will *only work for the user who generated it*?

I have step one implemented in my app (the oAuth2 flow, returning the ID of the Discord user), I just need to figure out a way to generate a link that is only valid for that user, and find a way to display it on the page when they return from authentication.

I can see in the Discord.js [documentation here](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/typedef/CreateInviteOptions) there is a property when generating an invite link called `targetUser`, but I'm not entirely clear on what this is supposed to do from reading it's description.

I also need a way of connecting Discord.js to the frontend of my web app in a secure way in order to get the link at all.

Any help at all on this would be hugely appreciated, thank you!

Comment: You could just use OAuth to get their user information into your database and then send them a link that you generated, and once a person joins the guild give them a role, etc to give them access to the server. Or use OAuth to join the guild for them.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`targetUser` is for inviting user into a livestream so you can't use it for this purpose. You can't create a invite link for a specific user, only a single use invite; but you can add the user trough oAuth2 directly to the server. 
 See https://discord.com/developers/docs/resources/guild#add-guild-member for more details.

Comment: You're a hero, checking this out now good sir. Thank you Felix!